# Can I scan two different arrays as input?

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

the input of my program would be two arrays as such:
2: [1,-1]
6: [0,1,1,1,1,0]

Where the first number is the number of elements in the array.
I've been trying to scan both, but for some reason the program prints the first array without letting me input the second. Does anyone know why that is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int h, hn, arrH[10]={0}, x, xn, arrX[10]={0};
    scanf("%i: [", &h);   //number of elements of arrH
    for(int i=0; h>0; i++){
        scanf("%i, ", &hn); //scan all elements of array until last one
        if(h==1){
           scanf("%i]\n", &hn); // last one scan with closing brackets
        }
        h--;  
        arrH[i]= hn;
    }
    
    scanf("%i: [", &x); // same process for arrX
    for(int i=0; x>0; i++){
        scanf("%i, ", &xn);
        if(x==1){
           scanf("%i]\n", &xn); 
        }
        x--;  
        arrX[i]= xn;
    }

    for(int i=0; arrH[i]!=0; i++ ){ //printing the 2 arrays
        printf("%i ", arrH[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; arrX[i]!=0; i++ ){
        printf("%i ", arrX[i]);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if anyone knows what I am doing wrong, thank you!

Comment: `for(int i=0; arrH[i]!=0; i++ )`   doesn't loop from 0 to the number at the front of the array

Comment: Tip: Don't get so enthusiastic about declaring everything on one line. Split those definitions up. It's easy to get burned with `int a, b = 0` where `a` is uninitialized.

Comment: caccia, "but for some reason the program prints the first array without letting me input the second." --> Step 1: test the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: caccia, Design redundancy: `2: [1,-1]` encode the array length twice: `2: 1,-1` or `[1,-1]` is sufficient.  Redundant data creates trouble when out of sync like `3: [1,-1]`.  Redundant data creates trouble when out of sync like `3: [1,-1]`.

Comment: `for(int i=0; h>0; i++)` and `if(h==1)` won't win you any awards. Use conventional indexing: `for( int i = 0; i < h; i++ )` and `if( i == h-1 )` to avoid ruffling feathers... You've lost the number of "loaded" values inserted into the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

i think i know where it is.
First of all you ask the user to decide the size of the tab, but you already give a size before by doing arrH[10] so it creates a tab with the size of 10 * int so 10 * 4octets.

you should use malloc instead to manage memory dynamically i guess.
And maybe the problem where it skip the input for the second tab comes from memory's problem of the computer.

Try to put some printf in your code to see where it go or not i guess. By using your code, it asked me too much numbers when i tried to fill tab.

Here's a example of how i would do that (in 1 function for the example):

```
int main(void) 
{
    int max1 = 0; //size of tab1
    int max2 = 0; //size of tab2
    int tmp = 0; //variable who'll take users's intput to fill both tab
    int *tab1 = {0}; 
    int *tab2 = {0};

    /* fill both tab */

    printf("give the size of the tab1:\n");
    scanf("%i", &max1);
    tab1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * max1); //setup the size of the first tab by user's intput
    if(!tab1) //test if malloc failed
        return (-1);
    printf("give %i value(s) to fill the tab:\n", max1);
    for (int i = 0; i < max1; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &tmp);
        tab1[i] = tmp;
    }
    printf("give the size of the tab2:\n");
    scanf("%i", &max2);
    tab2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * max2);
    if (!tab2) { //test if malloc failed
        free(tab1); //remember to free tab1 before exiting the function
        return (-1);
    }
    printf("give %i value(s) to fill the tab:\n", max2);
    for (int i = 0; i < max2; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &tmp);
        tab2[i] = tmp;
    }


    /* display 2 tabs */
    printf("tab1:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < max1; i++) {
        printf("%i ", tab1[i]);
    }
    printf("\ntab2:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < max2; i++) {
        printf("%i ", tab2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    /* free tabs */
    free (tab1);
    free (tab2);
    return (0);
}
```

Output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxFA7.png)

And i don't think you can scanf("%i", &x) and putting other characters in scanf to fill your tab of int. It's a int's array and should contain only int.
But you can add others characters to display arrays as you want later with printf when you display arrays.

Good luck and have a nice day

Comment: This code does not parse the format that OP needs.